# How to convert codes to Ids from joined table and temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create many-to-many tables in SQL Server connected to Location and Country tables.

Name: `LocationCountry`

```
CREATE TABLE LocationCountry
(
    [LocationId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CountryId] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_LocationCountry] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LocationId] ASC, [CountryId] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LocationCountry] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_LocationCountry_Country] 
        FOREIGN KEY([CountryId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Country] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LocationCountry] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LocationCountry_Country]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LocationCountry] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_LocationCountry_Location] 
        FOREIGN KEY([LocationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LocationCountry] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LocationCountry_Location]
GO
```

I have a temp aggregation codes of countries, but now I need to convert them to Ids from Country and Location tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    LocCode nvarchar(3),
    NonResLocCode nvarchar(3)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #tmp (LocCode, NonResLocCode) VALUES ('AGO', 'GAB')
INSERT INTO #tmp (LocCode, NonResLocCode) VALUES ('AGO', 'GNQ')
INSERT INTO #tmp (LocCode, NonResLocCode) VALUES ('ARG', 'PRY')
INSERT INTO #tmp (LocCode, NonResLocCode) VALUES ('ARG', 'PER')
INSERT INTO #tmp (LocCode, NonResLocCode) VALUES ('ARG', 'URY')
INSERT INTO #tmp (LocCode, NonResLocCode) VALUES ('ARG', 'CHL')
...
```

Here are the `Country` and `Location` tables:

Country

```
+-----+---------+------+
| Id  |  Name   | Code |
+=====+=========+======+
| 1   | Austria | AUT  |
+-----+---------+------+
| 2   | Brasil  | BRA  |
+-----+---------+------+
```

Location

```
+--------+-----------+------+
|   Id   | StoreName | Code |
+========+===========+======+
| 222342 | TestName  | AUT  |
+--------+-----------+------+
| 12312  | TestName2 | BRA  |
+--------+-----------+------+
```

Basically I'm looking for a way to convert those codes into ID's.

For example:

LocationCountry

```
+------------+-----------+
| LocationId | CountryId |
+============+===========+
| 12312      | 2         |
+------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that would work:

```
INSERT INTO LocationCounty(CountryId,Locationid)
SELECT c.id,l.ID
FROM #tt  AS t
JOIN Country  AS c
    ON  c.Code = t.NonResLocCode
JOIN Location l
    ON  lCode = t.LocCode
```

Comment: hmm, Im getting for LocationId same Id https://i.imgur.com/v3S87AV.png

Comment: You have one location for several countries

Comment: yes, but I have different rows for Location as you can see above. 'AGO','ARG' in that temp table, so I need to have walking array also, for example if AGO = 22 in my Location table, and 'ARG' has id of 27, so I need to have 22|3242, and 27|626178

Comment: It's working now, it was a typo instead of Code, it should be CountryCode :) thanks!

Comment: @Stefan0309: Consider accepting and up voting the answer, if it solved your problem.

Comment: Well I have some weird issue. I have in my temp table 120 rows, but with this select statement, I have 166 rows.